# Is the SQL in brackets a scalar subquery?

Tags: sql, subquery, arcgis, terminology, scalar-subquery

I use GIS software that has a proprietary database called a [File Geodatabase](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-file-gdb/file-geodatabases.htm).

Their documentation https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm says:

> **SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS**

> **Subqueries**
>
> Subquery support in file geodatabases is limited to the following:
>
> - Scalar subqueries with comparison operators. A scalar subquery returns
>   a single value, for example:
>
>   `GDP2006 > (SELECT MAX(GDP2005) FROM countries)`
>
>   For file geodatabases, the set functions AVG, COUNT, MIN,
>   MAX, and SUM can only be used in scalar subqueries.
> - EXISTS predicate,
>   for example:
>
>   `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM indep_countries WHERE COUNTRY_NAME = 'Mexico')`

I have a query that I use to create a database view in a file geodatabase. The view runs without errors.

```
--species_records_latest_vw
--For each species group, select the row that has the latest date. 
--Does not break ties if there are multiple rows per species with the same date.

select
    *
from
    species_records
inner join
    (select
        t_species,
        max(t_date) as t_date 
    from
        species_records 
    group by
        t_species) l
on species_records.t_species = l.t_species 
and species_records.t_date = l.t_date
```

Sample Excel data: https://community.esri.com/ccqpr47374/attachments/ccqpr47374/arcgis-pro-ideas/27986/1/species_records.xlsx

Is the SQL in brackets a scalar subquery?

If it is, is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: When data & constraints are necessary to a question--perhaps to show that a scalar subquery actually always returns exactly (1 column &) 1 row--it should be in your post, to be cut & pasted & run as part of a [mre], not just at a link. But here the subquery isn't a scalar subquery & the Excel content isn't needed.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a scalar subquery. A scalar subquery only returns *one column* and *one row*, for *one total value*.

This is called a **derived table**.

Comment: Other possible names: Virtual table or inline view?

Comment: @User1974 Generally a virtual table is considered to be one that uses a `VALUES` clause, and an inline view is often used to mean a Common Table Expression.